# schedule number of web dynos by time of day

Tags: python, django, dynamic, heroku

Is there a way to use the Heroku scheduler to start and stop web dynos for specific periods of the day? Like say during business hours 2 dynos and at night only 1 dyno?

I really would like to avoid putting the normal user/pass credentials into the app itself, so I'm looking for a secure way to do this (apart from doing it manually each day for each app). Using the "heroku ps:scale web=2" directly would naturally be nice but as far as I know this is not supported.

Thanks for any feedback in advance...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can scale heroku dynos on a schedule by creating a script that uses the Heroku API. You then make an entry in your Procfile and call it via the Heroku Scheduler add-on. Here's how:

First you'll need to add the 'heroku' python module to your `requirements.txt`:

> heroku==0.1.2

Next, create a config var that contains your API key, so your script can use the API.

> heroku config:add HEROKU_API_KEY=your_api_key_string

You can find your API key [on your heroku account page](https://api.heroku.com/account/).

Now you'll be able to write a python script that scales your dynos. Here's a very basic script that accepts the number of dynos as a command-line argument.

```
import os
import sys

import heroku

"""Scale heroku web processes using the heroku python API."""

# you may want to add better argument processing, use argparse, etc.
dynos = int(sys.argv[1])
cloud = heroku.from_key(os.environ.get('HEROKU_API_KEY'))
app = cloud.apps['your_app_name']

try:
    # you may want to add a maximum dyno check here to prevent costly mistakes ;)
    webproc = app.processes['web']  
    webproc.scale(dynos)

except KeyError:
    # note: scaling to 0 dynos or attempting to scale up if 0 web dynos exist
    # both throw this error. Make sure you have at least one dyno.
    print >> sys.stderr, "Could not scale web processes - are there 0 web dynos running?"
```

Then you can either define your entire task inside the Heroku Scheduler web page, or define it inside your Procfile and call the Procfile process name from the web page. I prefer the latter, as it makes it easy to update or change the process without having to log in to heroku's website.

So, create entries in your Procfile:

```
scale_up: python scale.py 2
scale_down: python scale.py 1
```

And then schedule them:

[image: [image]]

And voila! Your dynos will now scale up or down at the specified time of day.

--

Note that once you have created a scheduled task on the Scheduler web page you can't edit the time of day it runs, but if you create a new task you can set the time day and then delete your old task.

**Note 2:** The heroku python API seems to throw a KeyError if you try to scale down to 0 dynos, or if you try to scale up if 0 web dynos currently exist. To avoid both, just don't scale down to 0 dynos.

Comment: This answer was incredibly detailed. Thank you so much for investing all this time. It is very much appreciated... naturally I accept your answer as _the_ answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! :) I'm glad it helped. Who knows maybe some other people will find it useful too ;)

Comment: My colleague asked Heroku support about this and they said this would work but did not recommend using Heroku Scheduler as it is a "best-effort" service, meaning that it is not guaranteed to run or might run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

It's not built into the platform but should be pretty easy to implement via scheduler and using your API token.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do now with heroku addon plugin crontogo
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/crontogo

Note: This is a paid plugin, and available only in US/Europe regions as of Oct 2021

Refer https://crontogo.com/blog/how-to-schedule-heroku-cli-commands/

Setup 2 jobs

**1st Job “Dyno scale down” :**

Cron expression: 0 18 * * 1-5

Command: heroku dyno:scale web=1:Standard-1X

This job will run on weekdays (Monday to Friday) at 6pm and scale the app down to 1 Standard-1X dyno.

**2nd Job “Dyno scale up” :**

Cron expression: 0 9 * * 1-5

Command: heroku dyno:scale web=2:Standard-1X

This job will run on weekdays (Monday to Friday) at 9am and scale the app up to 2 Standard-1X dynos.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this via the heroku scheduler, which is free compared to cron-to-go. Just fill in [your-app-name] and [your-token]. The token can be generated via the command-line-interface and the following command: `heroku authorizations:create`

```
curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/[your-app-name]/formation -d '{ "updates": [ { "quantity": 1, "size": "standard-1X", "type": "web" } ] }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -H "Authorization: Bearer [your-token]"
```