# Change Dyno types through the Heroku API

Tags: python, heroku

I have an app running in Heroku; I'm using the [Heroku scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) to run a python script that scales the number of dynos at particular times of the day, using the [python API](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py) (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961899/1237531)):

```
import heroku
cloud = heroku.from_key(os.environ.get('HEROKU_API_KEY'))
app = cloud.apps['myapp']
webproc = app.processes['web']
webproc.scale(1)
```

My question is: is there an API call to change Dyno *types*? For instance to change it from "standard 1X" to "standard 2X" or to "hobby".

Thanks

Comment: has this been fixed yet?

Comment: Not that I know of: there's a community-developed python API, but I don't think it can perform a change in dyno types. https://github.com/martyzz1/heroku3.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chat with the Heroku support has confirmed that the python API has no command to perform this operation; I have therefore resorted to add the following script to the app (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153236/1237531)):

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz | tar xz
mv heroku-client/* .
rmdir heroku-client
PATH="bin:$PATH"

heroku dyno:type hobby --app MYAPP
```

Changing `hobby` with `standard-1x` or `standard-2x` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not via the Python API (which is deprecated), but via the regular HTTP API you can do:

```py
requests.patch(
    f"https://api.heroku.com/apps/{APP_ID_OR_NAME}/formation",
    json={"updates": [{"size": DYNO_TYPE, "type": "web"}]},
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}",
    },
)
```

Here using the [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests)-library.

I believe the dyno size update applies to all process types -- here I've only list `web` -- at least when going from e.g. "free" to "hobby". Otherwise, you simply add those other process types to the `updates`-list.

See Heroku API docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation-batch-update