# `heroku` is not accessible on Heroku (not kidding)

Tags: python, git, heroku

I have a python project hosted on Heroku which is trying to do the following:

1. Create git repos
2. Launch on heroku
3. Change dyno size to Hobby.

I have been integrating with the Heroku Platform API only to find out that step 3 is not achievable through their API. (see [Change Dyno types through the Heroku API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122456/change-dyno-types-through-the-heroku-api))

I tried to `subprocess.call(['heroku', 'dyno:type', 'hobby'])` only to find out that **the command heroku is not available on heroku**. This is confirmed by `heroku run bash`.

Hence, I've thought about downloading the heroku client directly, attaching it to my repo and executing the heroku client through my python webserver.

However, I actually don't know how this could be done. My questions:

1. How can I even navigate to my repo path from within my webserver?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

For those of you still doubting whether I have ran `heroku` properly on my webserver:

```
@app.route("/<cloaker_id>")
def hello(cloaker_id):  
  subprocess.call(['heroku', 'apps'])
```

Results in

```
2017-04-30T08:33:48.108374+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-30 08:33:48,107] ERROR in app: Exception on /blah [GET]
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705906+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705908+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705908+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705909+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705910+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705911+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705914+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705915+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705916+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705916+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705917+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705918+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/run.py", line 20, in hello
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705918+00:00 app[web.1]:     subprocess.call(['heroku', 'apps'])
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705919+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705920+00:00 app[web.1]:     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705921+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705922+00:00 app[web.1]:     errread, errwrite)
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705923+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705923+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise child_exception
2017-04-30T08:30:06.705924+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is confirmed by `heroku run bash`, is that succeeding or failing? Where are you running that and the `subprocess.call()`?

Comment: @NickT subprocess complains that `heroku` process is not found. Running `heroku` in heroku run bash also complains that command is not found

Comment: I assume you're talking about running on the Heroku instance; is it supposed to have the Heroku agent on it? Install it yourself?

Comment: Did you try updating your heroku cli?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in your local heroku directory? heroku run bash will run if you're in your local one but report an error if you're in another project directory. I assume you've installed the Heroku Toolbelt?